# How can I send a DataGridView WM_PAINT message, directly to a DC (device context), using Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I want to do what I have done in the past, using the old VB6. Subclassing has changed a lot since VB6 and I still want to do the same:

I need to intercept WM_PAINT of DataGridView, send it to a memory device context (to avoid flickering), make some visual changes, like place a *logo* over all over the grid. With VB6, was easy to do. I have spend hours trying to convert VB6/API code to Visual Basic Express 2010 code, without success.

So, if anybody know how to do it ... let me know please.

Thank's on advance

Abílio Rodrigues

Answer (score 1):

You can't send messages to device contexts, only to windows. Get the handle of the window for the control, and send the message there.

Comment: MySubclassedGrid = CallWindowProc(GetProp(hw, "lpPROC"), hw, lMsg, ByVal BackBuffDC, 0&)

Comment: the upper code was made by myself in order to send WM_PAINT to a BackBuffer, using VB6, inside a Case WM_PAINT ...and it works ! However, i don't know how to use this code inside a OnPaint override. There are something left ...

Comment: So in other words you're looking for `SendMessage()`?